# Mac Laptops do not see printer anymore

Tags: macos, drivers, printer, network-printer

I have a bunch of laptops that run OSX 10.4 and whenever I go to add the IP of the printer I get the "can't find the software/drivers".

What are some debug steps I can take to get the printer added and working? (I am new to apple)

Comment: You may need to manually install the drivers (go to your printer's support site and find them).  What all have you tried?

Comment: So far all I have tried is letting the system do things manually.

Comment: We expect that you try to do a bit on your own before asking questions, I would find the drivers manually on the support site then and see if you run into errors there - then ask.

Answer (score 0):

`lpadmin` is the Unix tool for adding and deleting printers. With Apple Remote Desktop you can execute this command as root remotely to change client settings.

First you need to make sure there is either a PPD or a .gz of the printer driver in the client's directory. The path is:

```
/Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/
```

To get the list of the user's printers, use:

```
lpstat -p
```

From this list you may see a printer to delete (here, for example, *homeinkjet*). The command is:

```
lpadmin -x homeinkjet
```

Note: you can remove more than one at a time by following the command with a wordspace, a semicolon, and another word space.

```
lpadmin -x homeinkjet ; lpadmin -x brokenlaserjet
```

To add a printer to a remote user, use the following syntax (omitting the [brackets]):

```
lpadmin -p [name of printer as it appears in client printer list] -L [location]
 -E -v lpd://[new printer's IP] -P [path to printer's PPD]
```

Note that you must use the escape character "\" for word spaces in the PPD path. For example, the "HP LaserJet 5000 Series.gz" is `HP\ LaserJet\ 5000\ Series.gz`.